# Not booting off TPM with USB disk inserted

Tags: encryption, usb-drive, luks, tpm

At reboot, with USB sticks inserted, the TPM will not allow passphraseless booting of the server. With a USB HDD inserted passphraseless booting of the server is possible.

Our servers are running Centos 8.3 with Linux kernel version 4.18.0-240.
TPM2 modules are used with LUKS version 1 encryption of an LVM group consisting of several partitions including / /home swap etc. LUKS header slot 0 is used for the passphrase, and slot 1 for the TPM.

The LUKS header slot 1 is bound to PCR values 0,1,2 and 3. Thus the BIOS (0), BIOS configuration (1), Options ROM (2) and Options ROM configuration (3).

From what I read the Options ROM consists of the firmware that is loaded during the POST boot process. If any changes occur from the state of the system when the TPM was signed, the TPM won't allow the system to boot without a passphrase. As USB sticks have firmware that might get loaded during the boot process, I initially thought that binding only to PCR values 0 and 1, ie without the Options ROM, would solve the problem. This did not work.

Any advice on why it won't boot from the TPM with a USB stick attached will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have figured out which PCR value changes after a USB stick gets inserted and the system reboots. By not binding to that PCR value we managed to boot off the TPM with a USB stick inserted.

In our case PCR 1 (BIOS config) kept changing when a USB stick was inserted and the system rebooted.

The command we used to query the PCR values was `tpm2_pcrread`. This lists the PCR values in sha1 and sha256. We redirected the stdout of the PCR values to a file before and after the changes and using `diff` command we monitored the changes between each file.